# FieldError django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Please I need help, I dont know where the problem is coming from, please see the code below

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def post_feed_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
    profiles = user.follow_user.all()
    followed_users_id = []
    if profiles.exists():
        followed_users_id = [x.user.id for x in profiles]
    followed_users_id.append(user.id)
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(user__id__in=followed_users_id).order_by("-date_posted")
    serializer = PostSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=200)
```

I keep getting this error: Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: author, author_id,
although, in my models, I dont have "User" what I have is "Author".
But I dont know where exactly to put in author. I think my problem is that i dont fully understand "request.user".

Please help!.

===========

This is the Profile and Follow models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=245, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='interests_user')
    stripe_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    one_click_purchasing = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    is_vendor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # vendor
    bvn = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    # follow_user = models.ManyToManyField('users.Follow') 
    

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    @property
    def followers(self):
        return Follow.objects.filter(follow_user=self.user).count()

    @property
    def following(self):
        return Follow.objects.filter(user=self.user).count()

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)


class Follow(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follow_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='follow_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    old_instance = models.ForeignKey('Follow', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is not None:
            self.old_instance = Follow.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"For: {self.user} // id: {self.id}"
    
class FollowerRelation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile = models.ForeignKey("Profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Can you share the models for `Profile` and `Follow`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Post` model apparently has no `user` field, but an `author` field, so you can filter with:

```
queryset = Post.objects.filter(
    author_id__in=followed_users_id
).order_by('-date_posted')
```

But that being said, you should not filter like that. Given your models you can do this in a single query and thus avoiding the *N+1 problem*. You can simply filter with:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def post_feed_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(
        author__follow_user__user=request.user
    ).order_by('-date_posted')
    serializer = PostSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=200)
```

Comment: Yes. I understand what you are saying, I just did it this way to check before I update it using models. Thank you so much. <3